# Is It Possible to Use the Block Editor’s Notification Feature to Send Another Notification After the Post Is Saved?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I have custom fields added to a custom post and I'm using the block editor to edit the custom posts. I'm saving the custom fields separately when the user hits the Update button. The block editor sends a notification when the post is saved but that one is for the post. Is it possible for me to use the block editor's notification system to send another notification relating to the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to do it Redux- way. Subscribe to post saving action (there are separate actions for save and auto-save) and dispatch a message using dispatch function.

Edit:

Inside blocks, there are better hooks to use, like useSelect. But, outside the block, in general block editor environmentm you have to use subscribe. In subsbscribe you are subscribed to every action dispatched to block editor. Inside the listener function you use wp.data.select to test current state of the store. You want to test  `isSavingPost` and `isAutosavingPost` selectors.
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/#issavingpost/data/data-core-editor/#isautosavingpost

To wrap everything up:

```js
const unsuscribe = wp.data.subscribe(() =>
        {
            if (wp.data.select('core/editor').isSavingPost() || wp.data.select('core/editor').isAutosavingPost()) {
   // your code
}

        });
```

Comment: I suppose it's not the same as wp.data.subscribe in plain JavaScript? There's also a wp.data.dispatch. I have no experience with Redux.

Comment: Yes, it is wp.data.subscribe and wp.data.dispatch, though it is much more elegant to use them with import statement, as a part of webpack build process. See edited answer for more details

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it the Redux way next time. It might take too long to start from scratch. Any chance you know why is it that when I'm subscirbed to isSavingPost() it saves the custom field twice?

Comment: By the way, I found wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createNotice() and that's the one I'm currently using but I was hoping to use the notification that appears on the bottom left part that says "Post update." The black one.

Comment: "Any chance you know why..." - very probably because another action fires subscribe, while isSavingPost selector is still true - define persistent variable which you would set to same value as custom field in the moment when you write custom field value. Before writing custom field test if value of variable is the same as value you intend to write and do not write if it is.

Comment: Note that subscribe is not the same as event - it fires on every action and when it fires you can test state of the store with selectors. When you need something like an event it is a little more complicated to achieve that - hence that extra variable "hack". Take a look at official Redux example - they are also using it: https://redux.js.org/api/store#example-1

Comment: "By the way, I found wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createNotice()..." - use snackbar for notice type, like this:
`wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createSuccessNotice('Your message', {isDismissible: true, id: 'some-id', type: 'snackbar'});`